# Como criar uma coluna com base em outro dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, comparação, numpy, dataframe

Gostaria de saber como criar um coluna num dataframe com base no código de outro dataframe em Python. Por exemplo, eu tenho:

df A:

```
letra
c
b
d
c
a
```

df B:

```
letra codigo
   a       10
   b       20
   c       30
   d       40
```

Resultado esperado é o df A ficar assim:

```
letra codigo
   c    30
   b    20
   d    40
   c    30
   a    10
```

Comment: Não entendi porque a pergunta foi definida como fora de escopo, mas enfim, testa usando `map`. `df['codigo'] = df['letra'].map(df2.set_index('letra')['codigo'])`